# What is the easiest way to check an integer's remainder for modulus 2 in Nasm assembler?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, modulo, modulus

For example:

```
int x = 35;
if( x%2==1) { //do something }
```

I just want to check the modulus value without assigning the result to `x`.

Assume that value is in `eax`, so I can use `DIV` instruction, then put back the original value to `eax` etc.. but that seems inefficient. Can you suggest a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To branch according to the modulo 2 of a value in `al`/`ax`/`eax`/`rax`:

```
    test al,1
    jnz is_odd

is_even:
    ; do something for even numbers.

is_odd:
    ; do something for odd numbers.
```

However, if all you want is the modulo value, you don't need any branches.

```
test al,1
setnz bl   ; modulo 2 of al/ax/eax/rax is now in bl.
```

Comment: even easier, if you don't mind overwriting the old value, `and al, 1`

Comment: @JanDvorak `test al,1` **is the same as** `and al,1` except that `and` overwrites the result, `test` only updates the flags. So I see no benefit in using `and al,1` here. Also `and al,1` may be slower than `test al,1`, because the following instructions may need to wait for the result in `al`. Also, OP specifically wants "to check the modulus value without assigning the result to x".

Answer (score 3):

If the low bit is on, it is not divisible by two:

```
test   x, 1
jne    somewhere_when_odd
```

Comment: `and x,1` is destructive in `x86` assembly. `test x,1` does the same, but is not destructive (updates flags but does not save the result in `x`; see my answer below).